# Nifi ConsumeJMS happens "Schema failover not found" when subscribing a topic from ActiveMQ

Tags: apache-nifi, activemq-artemis

- Environment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server
- Nifi version: 1.16.0

I have a ConsumeJMS which will uses a JMSConnectionFactoryProvider to subscribe a topic from an ActiveMQ-artemis.

The JMSConnectionFactoryProvider is configured as below:

[image]

The ComsumeJMS processor is configured as below:
[image]
[image]

When start the ConsumeJMS processor, it appears below error:
[image]

The key error message is "Schema failover not found". But if I use GetJmsTopic processor with the same URI, the GetJmsTopic can work.

So, how do I fix the error of "Schema failover not found"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `failover` schema is supported by the OpenWire JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ "Classic", but it's **not supported** by the core JMS client shipped with ActiveMQ Artemis which you're using (i.e. `artemis-jms-client-all-2.19.0.jar`). You should use a URL like this instead:

```
(tcp://192.168.10.65:61616,tcp://192.168.11.65:61616)
```